# Material-ui search icon needed to be in right side of input box

Tags: reactjs, search, material-design, material-ui

[image: Material UI search input]

I want the search icon to appear on the right side of the input box in material-ui (react). Are there any classes to be added for this?

here is the code snippet

```
 import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
  <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          </div>
```

Comment: Share the code snippet you are using for this. Just the image would not help to provide the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `endAdornment` in `InputBase`:

```
<InputBase
  placeholder="Search…"
  inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
  endAdornment={<SearchIcon/>}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Place of `endAdornment` just put `startAdornment` that will work.

Here is my Code as an Example

```
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { Container, InputAdornment, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";

const MyFilesIndex = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

return (
  <div>
      <Container maxWidth="md">
        <TextField
          id="search"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search"
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={handleChange}
          sx={{ width: 350 }}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <SearchIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }}
        />
      </Container>
    </div>
);
```